# LINQ FirstOrDefault Returing more than 1 result

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get the oldest record from a list using LINQ. I just want the *TOP* record essentially. It looked like `FirstOrDefault` method does the trick but upon testing my query in LINQPad. I'm getting a dataset not just one record..

Anyone know how to just return **1 record**?

```
List<Event> schedule = new List<Event>()
{
    new Event(){eventID = 776734, eventName = "HGP", eventStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2011-09-01"), eventEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2011-09-18"), runningHours = 0.0000, runningStartStops = 0.0000},
    new Event(){eventID = 776735, eventName = "CI", eventStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-10-01"), eventEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-10-11"), runningHours = 0.0000, runningStartStops = 0.0000},
    new Event(){eventID = 776736, eventName = "HGP", eventStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2014-03-01"), eventEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2014-03-18"), runningHours = 0.0000, runningStartStops = 0.0000},
    new Event(){eventID = 779236, eventName = "CI", eventStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-11-10"), eventEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-11-23"), runningHours = 2774.3300, runningStartStops = 111.3400},
    new Event(){eventID = 779364, eventName = "MA", eventStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-03-11"), eventEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-04-04"), runningHours = 4176.0200, runningStartStops = 104.3400},
    new Event(){eventID = 779365, eventName = "CI", eventStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-04-05"), eventEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2019-04-13"), runningHours = 8054.6700, runningStartStops = 232.5100},
    new Event(){eventID = 779366, eventName = "HGP", eventStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2021-04-02"), eventEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2021-04-19"), runningHours = 13473.1300, runningStartStops = 389.3500},
    new Event(){eventID = 779367, eventName = "CI", eventStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2023-03-31"), eventEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2023-04-08"), runningHours = 18930.8900, runningStartStops = 520.0200}
};

var q = from evt in schedule
         where "MA,HGP".Contains(evt.eventName)
         group evt by evt.eventID into x
         select x.OrderByDescending(t => t.eventStartDate).FirstOrDefault();

//LINQPad method to show results     
q.Dump();
```

Comment: Put your query in parentheses and put the `FirstOrDefault()` on the outside of those.

Comment: You are calling `FirstOrDefault` on the groups, so you are returning only the first event of each group. If you want the first group's first event use `q.FirstOrDefault()`. But maybe you want to order before the `GroupBy`, then you get also the first group according to the date not an arbitrary one.

Comment: Not sure whether this title should be re-worded. `FirstOfDefault` would only return more than 1 if it had a bug, which is unlikely.

Comment: On a side note, your query will select items with `eventName = "A,H"` too.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: it possibly returns multiple groups that contain only one event each

Comment: @TimSchmelter - `FirstOrDefault` cannot return more than 1 result. Whether `FirstOrDefault` is being misused or the results of which being misinterpreted is another thing.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: no, that's why he only gets one event per group. Note that he doesn't use `FirstOrDefault` on the whole query but only on `x` which is a group of events.

Comment: @ArghyaC Thanks for the note! That will be the next problem to fix! Lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to close your query in parenthesis:

```
var q = (from evt in schedule
         where "MA,HGP".Contains(evt.eventName)
         group evt by evt.eventID into x
         select x.OrderByDescending(t => t.eventStartDate)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Your query is selecting the first element of each sorted group.

### Update

But why do you need to group if you just are looking the newest event? Try changing the `group by` to an `order by`:

```
var q = (from evt in schedule
         where "MA,HGP".Contains(evt.eventName)
         order evt by evt.eventStartDate 
         select x).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or, as @TimSchmelter recommended in his comment, order your elements before group them.

Comment: It seems that only want one event, so `First` after the `OrderByDescending` and `FirstOrDefault` at the end. Instead of using parentheses i recommend to use a second variable. That increases readability and testability without making it less efficient(due to LINQ's deferred execution).

Comment: This fixes the original issue. Will mark as solution but for some reason its returning the oldest record not the newest. Tried both `OrderBy` & `OrderByDescending`. Its returning the first row  in the sample date should be the second to last row.

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat: i have mentioned the reason in [my first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338919/linq-firstordefault-returing-more-than-1-result?noredirect=1#comment56419120_34338919) to your question. Use `order by evt.eventStartDate desc` before the group-by, then you don't need one on the groups and you also get the newest group. Currently you are just getting an arbitrary group because there is no order-by at all.

Comment: Just tried that. Solved the ordering issue. Thx @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain the why to the already posted answers.

The [OrderByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534855%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns an IOrderedEnumerable and you are calling the FirstOrDefault() method on that return value. 
Enclosing the query in "()" like stated octavioccl's answer will call the FirstOrDefault() method on the query result instead.